# Vectorizing code that includes conditional statement

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I've been using for loops for a script I've been working on, and I think the for loops are making the script run too slow. I think I could pick up a lot of speed with vectorization, but I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to vectorize my code. I'm copying some simple sample code that more or less mimics what I'm trying to accomplish in my actual code to make the question easier to follow. (Sorry if it's not the most elegant or technically sound. I'm still getting experience with Python.)

```
import numpy as np

def create_combo(input1,input2):

    combo = input1 + input2
    return combo

def another_combo(monitor,scalar_1,scalar_2):

    add_more = monitor + scalar_1 + scalar_2

    return add_more

# Initialize monitor
monitor = 0

# Initialize a threshold variable
threshold = 15

# Create input arrays
primary_1 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
primary_2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

primary_1 = np.array(primary_1)
primary_2 = np.array(primary_2)

storage_vec = []
for i in range(5):
    # Create input variables
    scalar_1 = 0.5
    scalar_2 = 2

    # Call the create_combo function 
    combination = create_combo(primary_1[i],primary_2[i])

    # call the another_combo function
    add_on = another_combo(monitor,scalar_1,scalar_2)

    monitor = combination + add_on

    # Check if monitor exceeds threshold
    if monitor > threshold:
        # Store the index if so
        storage_vec.append(i)
        # Reset the variable, monitor
        monitor = 0
```

I can understand how it would be easy to vectorize the function named create_combo. And I can also see that it would be simple to make the variable named monitor a vector as well.

What I'm having trouble wrapping my head around is how I could reset that monitor variable at specific points in the vector and continue doing computations with monitor after it has been reset. So, I've been working with monitor as a scalar and doing computations on each element of the inputs to the functions. However, this seems to be way too slow, and I know vectorizing typically speeds things up.

I read that perhaps the np.where() function could help, but I'm also not sure how to apply that in this situation.

Any guidance?

Comment: what does `create_combo` do exactly?

Comment: `where` is not an iterator.  It's arguments are evaluated in full first.  Your code is inherently serial, so doesn't 'vectorize'.  Sometimes by looking the results from 'above and sideways' we can see ways of bypassing the serial nature, but that's hard to generalize.

Comment: In your case monitor increase linearly by a step of `21.5` until it reach `40`. So you can just made a ceil division between those two number: `n=-(-40//21.5)` so `n=2` and now we find when monitor is reset with a simple modulo operator: `storage_vec = np.where(np.r_[:5]%n==1)[0]`.

Comment: your `create_combo` func is returning a scaler which is just the sum of the last two elements of the arguments. Is this what you want? if yes, then why are you even looping?

Comment: @Shubham good point. That was a mistake from hastily making this sample code. I edited the post to better reflect the concept

Answer (score 0):

Your example if probably over complicated (or your example is not complete).

But if we want to create the `storage_vec` easily we can noticed that monitor increase by 21.5 after each step until it reach the threshold.

So the vector `storage_vec` can simply be computed with:

```
#Increase value:
inc = primary_1[-1]+primary_2[-1]+scalar_1+scalar_2 # = 21.5 
#floor division
fd = threshold//inc
#ceil division
cd = -(-threshold//inc)
#storage_vec 
storage_vec = np.r_[fd:10:cd]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My example functions/inputs may have not represented my problem in an ideal manner. Maybe a more physical explanation can add some clarity.
We can pretend that monitor is the volume of water contained in a bucket. We fill this bucket continuously. Each time the bucket fills up (so when monitor hits a threshold value), we want to dump out the water in the bucket and begin refilling the bucket. The bucket doesn't necessarily fill up at regular intervals though. We can predict how the bucket fills using the input vectors that represent how inputs vary with time.